# Using Custom User DB Structure in Mysql for Django 1.8

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a question regarding the table structure for `User` if I am extending its functionalities, using a MySQL database.

Given the **models.py** file

```
class LibraryUser(models.Model):
  user_id = models.OneToOneField(User)
  is_catalogue_subscriber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
  is_research_subscriber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
  library_membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I have a table structure for SQL

```
CREATE TABLE library_user(
  user_id int(10) primary key
  is_catalogue_subscriber integer(1) DEFAULT 1
  is_research_subscriber = integer(1) DEFAULT 1
  library_membership_number = varchar(16)
)
```

So now, when I fire up my server and access the accounts in the admin page, Django is throwing an error:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1054, "Unknown column 'library_user.id' in 'where clause'")
```

Comment: You should use django migrations for handling SQL. Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/. Don't create own SQL unless required. Just create models and run `./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`. More info in the link

Comment: Hello @BogdanIulianBursuc the thing is that I am integrating Django to an existing application with an existing set of library users. Hence, I want to leverage on the `User` model for authentication.

Comment: then check [the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) about how to extend the User model

Comment: use `user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)`, i.e. drop the `_id` in the attribute name

Comment: Hi @Pynchia let me try this solution before I close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)`

i.e. drop the _id in the attribute name.

In case you simply want to define a richer user model (i.e. add more attributes) you can

> use a one-to-one relationship to a model containing the fields
>   for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a
>   profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a
>   site user. For example you might create a LibraryUser model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LibraryUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_catalogue_subscriber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_research_subscriber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    library_membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Assuming an existing LibraryUser Fred Smith who has both a User and LibraryUser model, you can access the related information using Django’s standard related model conventions:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='fsmith')
>>> freds_department = u.libraryuser.department
```

Then to add the profile model’s fields to the user page in the admin do

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from my_user_profile_app.models import LibraryUser

# Define an inline admin descriptor for Employee model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class LibraryUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = LibraryUser
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'libraryuser'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (LibraryUserInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

All taken from the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that by default django models automatically include an `id` field that maps to models.AutoField().

You need to specify that your DB table id is `user_id` instead of `id`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

You want to make your `user_id` the primary key. It should work by adding `primary_key=True` to that field, like:

```
class LibraryUser(models.Model):
  user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
  is_catalogue_subscriber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
  is_research_subscriber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
  library_membership_number = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: Hey! I think your solution is correct. Instead of `user_id`, I used `user`. Let me confirm if this is correct before I give the correct sign to you?

Comment: You are right. Using only `user` instead of `user_id` will correct another issue too. Because django suffixes the relational fields with `_id`